# How to block replace code in visual mode?

Tags: visual-mode

I have a list of items where I want to replace the first two characters:

```
a) item 1
b) item 2
c) item 3
```

What is the fastest way to make this:

```
* item 1
* item 2
* item 3
```

I have an approach with visual mode (Ctr-v, jjj, but need to do two replace commands. Iirc, this replacement can be done with 1 command)

Comment: Like `.,.+2s/^../*/` (or equivalently in a visual selection)? Why two replace commands? `2c` would replace two characters.

Comment: sometimes only the first line in the visual selection is changed, repeating then with . for the other lines messes things up.

Comment: @poseid are you in the habit of pressing `Ctrl-C` instead of `Esc`? This prevents, among other things, changes being applied to each line of a Visual-block selection.

Comment: that could be the main reason for confusion! thanks!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

**Visual-block selection:**

```
<C-v>
jjl
c*
<Esc>
```

**`:normal`:**

```
:,+2norm! cE*
```

**Substitution:**

```
:,+2s/^.\{2}/*
```

**Dot formula:**

```
cE*<Esc>
j.
j.
```

Comment: Crazy approach: using [textobj-word-column.vim](https://github.com/coderifous/textobj-word-column.vim) you can do `ciC*<esc>` and be done. Note: this plugin is a "do what I mean" plugin so it fails in unexpected places and ways, but the plugin is still useful in some easy cases like this.

Comment: interesting the normal and dot formula!

Comment: Note that for the Visual-block solution, you will only see text being typed on the first line. Once you hit `<Esc>`, it will fill in the remaining lines.

Comment: Any suggestions for a way to remember that c will replace? Like how ctrl+D(own)

Comment: @JordanMackie `c` is for "change".

Comment: For guys like me, this `<C-v>` is in fact `<Ctrl+v>` and `jjl` is selecting 2x down 1x right, which can be done with arrows. As commented `c` is for change which will replace selected rows with provided chars `*` (or any). `<esc>` will apply the change after small sleep time.

Answer (score 26):

Here is more efficient way of doing this:

1. Having cursor on the first item and 1st letter (<kbd>0</kbd>), enter 'blockwise' visual mode <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> and select the 1st column of your current paragraph by <kbd>}</kbd> (if your list is finished by new line), otherwise use different methods like *arrow keys* (to move around the selection), or pattern search <kbd>/c)</kbd> where `c` is your last element).
2. Move to the last symbol of your list by <kbd>k</kbd> and <kbd>l</kbd> (or using *arrow keys*), so two columns are selected which you want to change.
3. Change the selected text by pressing <kbd>c</kbd> and type your bullet symbol (`*`) and finish by hitting <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Works more efficiently especially in the longer lists.